# Identificando uma String como nome de váriavel Pascal

Tags: delphi, pascal

Tenho 50 váriaveis do tipo array e tenho um método que vai receber uma String contendo um nome de uma váriavel existente. Gostaria de saber qual é a forma ideal para identificar o valor da String recebida como uma das 50 váriaveis declaradas no programa.

Aqui está uma das 50 nomenclaturas de váriaveis:

```
var
x:array[1..4] of String;
```

Aqui está o método:

```
procedure IdentificarVariavel(s:String); 
begin
     //
     // tratar o valor da String s recebida como váriavel x;
     //
end;
```

Preciso tratar o valor da String s como uma váriavel.
**OBS:** não gostaria de criar um case.

Comment: Tenho quase certeza que existe uma forma menos complicada de fazer o que você está querendo fazer.

Comment: O único jeito que tenho em mente no momento, porém não ideal é fazendo um case e associando cada valor recebido.

Comment: A intenção seria "converter" esse valor da String, passando a reconhecê-lo como a váriavel declarada.

Comment: Mas qual o objetivo?

Comment: Esses arrays sempre terão o mesmo tamanho?

Comment: O objetivo é reconhecer o valor como uma váriavel, para ser mais claro tenho um projeto do técnico e no momento estou focando apenas em uma estrutura do programa. Se possível fazer isso sem utilizar case já ajudaria.

Comment: Correto, porém nomenclaturas e valores diferentes

Comment: Qual a versão do delphi? Onde estão declaradas essas variáveis?

Comment: Estou utilizando o Delphi XE6 (desenvolvimento móvel), mas penso que isso não influência de certa forma na sintaxe aplicada em Pascal, afinal você tem uma solução?

Comment: Influência se vc fizer uma solução usando RTTI

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discuss&#227;o no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18251/discussion-between-murilo-hl-ad-and-eprogrammernotfound).

Comment: Porquê não usar um array of array [1..4] of string?

Comment: Qual seria a aplicação desse recurso?

Comment: Utilize um `Hash`, mapeando de um nome de variável para o `array` correspondente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mesmo que exista uma gambiarra (o que eu duvido muito) que serialize identificadores locais em `String`, a proposta abaixo é mais simples e (em minha opinião) mais elegante.

```
interface
uses Vcl.Dialogs, Classes; 

type
    TMyArray = array[0..4] of String;
    TStringHash = class
    private
        FKeys : TStringList;
        FValues : Array of TMyArray;
        function GetContent(Key: String; Index : Integer): String;
        procedure SetContent(Key : String; Index : Integer; Value: String);
    public
        property Contents[Key : String; Index : Integer] : String read GetContent write SetContent; Default;
        constructor Create;
        function Count : Integer;
    end;

implementation

constructor TStringHash.Create;
begin
    inherited;
    FKeys := TStringList.Create;
    FKeys.Add('');
    SetLength(FValues, 1);
    FValues[0][0] := '';
end;

function TStringHash.Count: Integer;
begin
    Result := FKeys.Count;
end;

function TStringHash.GetContent(Key: String; Index : Integer) : String;
var
    I : Integer;
begin
    Result := '';
    I := FKeys.IndexOf(Key) ;
    if I > -1 then
        Result := FValues[I][Index];
end;

procedure TStringHash.SetContent(Key : String; Index : Integer; Value: String);
var
    I : Integer;
begin
    I := FKeys.IndexOf(Key) ;
    if I > -1 then
        FValues[I][Index] := Value
    else
    begin
        SetLength(FValues, Length(FValues) + 1);
        FValues[Length(FValues) - 1][Index] := Value;
        FKeys.Add(Key);
    end;
end;
```

Para a utilização basta instanciar `TStringHash` com a linha a seguir `MinhaHash := TStringHash.Create;`.

E para manipular valores use: `Valor := MinhaHash['NomeVar', 0];` e `MinhaHash['NomeVar', 0] :=  Valor;`.

### Exemplo

Crie um arquivo Test.dpr. Dê um duplo clique (supondo que você tem o Delphi Instalado) e após o Delphi abrir o arquivo cole o ([conteúdo](http://pastebin.com/vU5edQH1)) e compile (F9).

Comment: Murilo, se a resposta não esclareceu a dúvida, comente quando puder, por favor.